# how to resolve dbus dependency on libnih ./configure?

Tags: compiler-construction, vps, configure, dbus, upstart

In a vps environment, I just installed

```
dbus-1.6.8
```

required by

```
libnih-1.0.3
```

however, the installation for libnih stops here:

```
checking for DBUS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (dbus-1 >= 1.2.16) were not met:

No package 'dbus-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DBUS_CFLAGS
and DBUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

where do i set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable?

my path to dbus is:

```
/home/MYUSER/usr/local/bin/lib/dbus-1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the dbus-1.0 directory, it will probably have a pkg_config (pr somesuch) subdirectory.

Then, set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to include that subdir:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/MYUSER/usr/local/bin/lib/dbus-1.0/SUBDIR:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```